# How to grep -o with -n

Tags: linux, grep

I have two different greps like below

```
grep -on "\w*_text1 \w*" test.log
grep -n "text2"  test.log
```

How can I combine them into one?

Basically, I have to print words that contain `_text1` and lines that has `text2`

Expected result:

1:address**_text1**

2:12:53:32.087 INFO  .... - Saving **text2**

3:phone**_text1**

4:12:53:33.087 INFO  .... - Updating **text2**

Comment: Combine how? Please, add a sample input and expected output to the question.

Comment: @choroba I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want the combined results, this should do:

```
grep -on "\w*_text1 \w*\|.*text2.*" test.log
```

Explanation:

- The two patterns have been combined with `\|`.
- The second pattern has been surrounded by `.*` to match the entire line; this effectively disables `-o` for that particular pattern.

Sample output:

```
$ cat test.log
not this
begin foo_text1 bar end
and not this
hello text2 bye
finally not this

$ grep -on "\w*_text1 \w*" test.log
2:foo_text1 bar

$ grep -n "text2"  test.log
4:hello text2 bye

$ grep -on "\w*_text1 \w*\|.*text2.*" test.log
2:foo_text1 bar
4:hello text2 bye
```

Comment: Thnx, it works now. I forgot that it is regex and I can use `or` :)

Answer (score 0):

Use logic OR:

```
grep -onE "_text1|text2" test.log
```

Comment: It kinda works, but it does not print **whole line** where `text2` occurs

Comment: Then get rid of the -o: `grep -E` is enough.